# Add Labels to Bokeh hbar

Tags: python, bokeh

How can I Label the bars in the hbar-plot with values?

Is there a way to manipulate the values of the x-axis? To get rid of the negative numbers for example

```
from bokeh.palettes import GnBu3, OrRd3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]



exports = {'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
           '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
           '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}


imports = {'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [-1, 0, -1, -3, -2, -1],
           '2016'   : [-2, -1, -3, -1, -2, -2],
           '2017'   : [-1, -2, -1, 0, -2, -2]}

p = figure(y_range=fruits, height=350, x_range=(-16, 16), title="Fruit import/export, by year",
           toolbar_location=None)

p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=GnBu3, source=ColumnDataSource(exports),
             legend_label=["%s exports" % x for x in years])

p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=OrRd3, source=ColumnDataSource(imports),
             legend_label=["%s imports" % x for x in years])

p.y_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify a tick on an axis, you can use a [`formatter`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html).

To show only positiv values on the ticks, you can use the `FuncTickFormatter` and return the absolut value.

```
p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="return Math.abs(tick)")
```

To set Labels, you can use `LabelSet`, which can take a `ColumnDataSource`. It can be tricky to get the correct position for values.

### Minimal Example

I have to import `pandas` and `numpy` to get my solution work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, PrintfTickFormatter, FuncTickFormatter, LabelSet
from bokeh.palettes import GnBu3, OrRd3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]

exports = pd.DataFrame({'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
           '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
           '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]})


imports = pd.DataFrame({'fruits' : fruits,
           '2015'   : [-1, 0, -1, -3, -2, -1],
           '2016'   : [-2, -1, -3, -1, -2, -2],
           '2017'   : [-1, -2, -1, 0, -2, -2]})

p = figure(y_range=fruits, height=350, x_range=(-16, 16), title="Fruit import/export, by year",
           toolbar_location=None)

p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=GnBu3, source=ColumnDataSource(exports),
             legend_label=["%s exports" % x for x in years])

p.hbar_stack(years, y='fruits', height=0.9, color=OrRd3, source=ColumnDataSource(imports),
             legend_label=["%s imports" % x for x in years])

p.y_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None

# new stuff comes here
# get the labels and the labels position
labels = {
    'x': (
        list((imports[years].cumsum(axis=1) - imports[years]/2).to_numpy().flatten())
        + list((exports[years].cumsum(axis=1) - exports[years]/2).to_numpy().flatten())
    ),
    'y': list(np.array([i+0.5 for i in range(len(fruits))]).repeat(len(years)))*2,
    'labels': (
        list(imports[years].abs().astype(str).replace('^0$','', regex=True).to_numpy().flatten())
        +list(exports[years].abs().astype(str).replace('^0$','', regex=True).to_numpy().flatten())
    )
}

labels = LabelSet(x="x", y="y", text="labels", text_font_size="11px", text_color="#555555",
                  source=ColumnDataSource(labels), text_align='center')
p.add_layout(labels)

p.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="return Math.abs(tick)")

show(p)
```

[image: result]